# Greasemonkey: Why does this if statement always return true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, greasemonkey

This confuses me... I'm using waitforkeyelements on an ajax page... I have an if statement that should only pop up an alert if there is a button with the value "Accept Offer".  Unfortunately, it's popping the alert when the only 2 buttons have values of "Continue Exploring" and "Invest".  I have a feeling it has something to do with true/false stuff, but I can't figure out why getElementById is supposed to work used like this but my selector doesn't.  This DOES work if I add an `===something` but I want to know why it doesn't work like this.

So, when there are 2 buttons that have values of "Continue Exploring" and "Invest", I get an alert that says "Yes!" and then an alert that says "Invest".  Shouldn't it run the "else" when there isn't a button with the value "Accept Offer"?

```
function countit () {

  if ($( '.adv-action[value*="Accept Offer"]')){

    alert("Yes!")
    alert($('.adv-action').val())

   }

  else{
    alert("no")
    alert($('.adv-action').val())
   }
}

waitForKeyElements ('[value*="Continue Exploring"]', countit);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do

```
if ($( '.adv-action[value*="Accept Offer"]').length!=0){

    alert("Yes!")
    alert($('.adv-action').val())

   }

else{
    alert("no")
    alert($('.adv-action').val())
}
```

`$( '.adv-action[value*="Accept Offer"]')` returns an array and array will always equate to true, so check if it actually contains any element or not by equating its length to 0.

Comment: I'm an idiot! lol.... this is why going to school for the basics would help... I write great scripts, but I stumble when I hit basic knowledge stuff... it was able to be fixed (once you said array) by using - $( '.adv-action[value*="Accept Offer"]').val() Normally I would have realized that it should match the alert, but I was being thrown off by the use of "value" in the selector...  THANKS!

Comment: Hehe yeah! It helps others to identify the right answer, and earns me some rep as well! :)

Comment: To double check... if I use [name=] instead of [value*=] that also returns an array?

Comment: Yes, Its the $(elem) which returns the array.. Whatever the selector is